# Not able to scroll down in Chromedriver by selenium webdriver(Java)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to test scrolling functionality by selenium webdriver. Same is working in Firefox but not in chrome driver. Here is basic code I'm using for scrolling.

```
Actions a = new Actions(driver);
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='dsm-frame']"));
a.moveToElement(el).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(0, 1000000).release().perform();
```

Is there any specific reason that Action builder does not work in chrome? Kindly advise how it can be worked in Chrome driver.

Thanks

Comment: try `a.moveToElement(el).build().perform();`

Comment: you may try sending space like `el.sendKeys(Keys.SPACE);`

Comment: Try `((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);");`

Comment: I tried with a.moveToElement(el).build().perform() but it did not work. Why is that it is not working in Chrome but in Firefox only.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: @guy , i did not get any error. Code got executed on Chrome but the scroll down action did not happen.

Comment: Is it same to be a.moveByOffset(0, 1000000).release().perform(); ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `JavaScriptExecutor` for scrolling.

***Scroll Down***

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scr‌​ollHeight);");
```

***Scroll Up***

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,0);");
```

Comment: Can it be not done without Javascript executor and only using Selenium APIs.

Comment: you can try something like `driver.findElement(By.id("")).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);` for scroll down

Comment: I tried using sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN) but it throws error 'org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element' in chrome.

Comment: if these things aren't working. then you can go with `JavaScriptExecutor`

Comment: I tried using JavaScriptExecutor as said above to scroll down  but it is throwing exception ** org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: missing )**

Comment: There was some weight character in the script when I copied it from this answer, so try to copy this one which has worked for me: `window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);`

Answer (score 4):

So far below are my findings based on options I tired:

1.**Action builder class** : Works in Firefox but not in Chrome.Not sure why it did not work in Chrome.

2.`js.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");`: It neither worked in Firefox and Chrome. I guess this is something not suitable in my case.

3.`js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element);` :  It worked in both Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript Executer version (scrolls to bottom - best for my needs):

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);");
```

Webdrvier only version:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("INSERT_A_INPUT_BOX")).sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN);
```

This version only scrolls down one page. At first it wouldn't work for me because I was trying to focus on a random element not an input element, but it does work when focusing on something you can type into

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in Selenium (wrapped in Selenide):

This worked for me to scroll to a link that was off the bottom of the page:

```
if (isPhantomjs()){
    $(byText(linkType)).scrollTo().click();
} else {
    executeJavaScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", $(byText(linkType)));
    $(byText(linkType)).click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Scroll down:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
```

OR,also

```
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 250);");
```

For Scroll up:

```
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,-250)", "");
```

OR,

```
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, -250);");
```

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

I am not a specialist at all of java but I use chromedriver from vba and face the same problem. As I am not able to locate the webelements by XPATH / JSON, I use the source code of the page instead, senkeys tab until the webelement I search get the focus then this element becomes the ***activeelement*** so the ***scrollintoview*** on the element is accessible and I can refresh the source code of the page...

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to click the element after scrolling then try below snippet.

> Actions action = new Actions(driver);
>
> action.moveToElement(element).click().perform();

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).perform();
```